# Device MFT Implementation

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I would like to implement **Device** DMFT based on [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/stream/dmft-design).

Did anyone has any experience with it and could share code sample?

I did find some “**Driver** MFT” [code samples](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-driver-samples/tree/master/avstream/samplemft0) on the *Microsoft* website but none for “**Device** MFT”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [the sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/avstream/sampledevicemft) from MSFT.
You can compile and register using the `dll` file generated.