# Device MFT vs driver MFT

Tags: ms-media-foundation

It seems like windows MF (Media foundation) they have moved from Driver MFT's to Device MFT's for there UVC camera's.  Now this wouldn't be a huge problem but almost all of the examples are for Driver MFT's.  So i'm trying to figure out whats the difference.  So i could remake some of the examples to work.

This is inline with this users request for a Driver MFT example.
[Device MFT Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72101620/device-mft-implementation)

Comment: if found something [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/avstream/sampledevicemft)   An N stream source supporting DeviceMFT will have a single instance of the Device Driver Transform loaded, while MFT0 will have N instances for each pipeline process.

Comment: [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/stream/dmft-design#functional-overview) give you a overview of the call.  And they seem fairly similar.